# Connection String for HTML page not found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having some trouble connecting to my database server, and I can't figure out why.  I am using the following code:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Initial Catalog=ScheduleData;");
    var query = db.Query("SELECT name,manager,CDL FROM dbo.Employee");
}
```

The connection string works when I use it from a VBScript that I created to populate the database (the only change made to the string was to add the extra forward slash to account for the escape sequence), but when I try to load the page that contains this code, I get the error:

> Connection string 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data
>   Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Initial
>   Catalog=ScheduleData;' was not found.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Gabe Where and what ?

Comment: Put your connection string in your web.config. Create stored procs.

Comment: @Gabe, what kind of injection vulnerability is that?  Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @Gabe While what you mention is *"best practices"* I don't see how it's necessarily opening the OP to a SQL injection exploit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `Database.Open` expects the name of a connection string defined in your web.config.  Try using `Database.OpenConnectionString` instead.  [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569301%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

Comment: I think this might be the problem- I changed the method call as you said, and I am no longer getting the "Connection string not found" message, though I am getting errors regarding "keyword 'server' not supported"